# Representing Variable Filter size in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, filter, window

I am working on a filter in which the instead of using fixed size filtering window, I use a adaptive window size based on noise density. For example, let say the window size is 3x3, it has 9 pixels. when all these 9 pixels are detected as corrupted pixels it is useless to proceed to next step as I need some noisy free pixels in window to process next step. In this case, I change the window size to 5x5 and scan again. If once again all the pixels(25 pixels) are detected as corrupted, I go for 7x7 window. To implement I have written a code but it is too large as I represented all the elements in each window. I am unsure to implement it otherwise but I am sure there will other easy way to do it.

The Code, I written for the above stated purpose is

```
if((S1==1) && (S2==1))

        5x5 window===> V=[L(p-2,q-2) L(p-2,q-1) L(p-2,q) L(p-2,q+1) L(p-2,q+2) L(p-1,q-2) L(p-1,q-1) L(p-1,q) L(p-1,q+1) L(p-1,q+2) L(p,q-2) L(p,q-1) L(p,q+1) L(p,q+2) L(p+1,q-2) L(p+1,q-1) L(p+1,q) L(p+1,q+1) L(p+1,q+2) L(p+2,q-2) L(p+2,q-1) L(p+2,q) L(p+2,q+1) L(p+2,q+2)]; % 5x5 window

        for k=1:24
            if((V(k) == 0) || (V(k) == 255))

            else
              N(a)=V(k);
              a=a+1;
            end
        end 

        if((a-1)>= 1)
        Y(p,q)=round(Median(N(1:a-1)));
         %disp(Y(p,q));
        a=1;
       else
         7x7 window===>   V1=[L(p-3,q-3) L(p-3,q-2) L(p-3,q-1) L(p-3,q) L(p-3,q+1) L(p-3,q+2) L(p-3,q+3) L(p-2,q-3) L(p-2,q-2) L(p-2,q-1) L(p-2,q) L(p-2,q+1) L(p-2,q+2) L(p-2,q+3) L(p-1,q-3) L(p-1,q-2) L(p-1,q-1) L(p-1,q) L(p-1,q+1) L(p-1,q+2) L(p-1,q+3) L(p,q-3) L(p,q-2) L(p,q-1) L(p,q+1) L(p,q+2) L(p,q+3) L(p+1,q-3) L(p+1,q-2) L(p+1,q-1) L(p+1,q) L(p+1,q+1) L(p+1,q+2) L(p+1,q+3) L(p+2,q-3) L(p+2,q-2) L(p+2,q-1) L(p+2,q) L(p+2,q+1) L(p+2,q+2) L(p+2,q+3) L(p+3,q-3) L(p+3,q-2) L(p+3,q-1) L(p+3,q) L(p+3,q+1) L(p+3,q+2) L(p+3,q+3)]; % 7x7 window
```

Similarly, I have used windows upto 11x11. I want to represent V and V1 vector easily rather than writing these much of codes.

Comment: @Barnabas Szabolcs Please see this

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary window centered at `[p,q]` of size `n` can be read from an image as

```
halfSize = floor(n/2); %# n has to be odd
window = image(p-halfSize:p+halfSize,q-halfSize:q+halfSize);
```

Note that you want to pad your image with the maximum value of `halfSize`, or alternatively, test that e.g. `p>halfSize` and `p<imageSize-halfSize+1` (same for `q`), so that you don't get indexing errors.

Comment: Thanks. i will check this out...I did not understand the alternative explanation.. i am very new to matlab.. I am unable to grasp the idea

Comment: @user101509: What I mean is that you have to make sure that your window is always contained inside the image. So if e.g. `(p,q)` is `(1,1)`, then your algorithm will have a problem.